# Create ResourceQuota objects to be deployed for each Namspace in repository

Tags: kubernetes, azure-devops, opa

Need to create new `ResourceQuota` object, one for each namespace.

The default ResourceQuota should be `2 CPU` and `10 GB` per namespace.

Any solutions for the above scenario.

Example I tried:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ResourceQuota
metadata:
  name: mem-cpu-demo
spec:
  hard:
    requests.cpu: "2"
    requests.memory: 10Gi
    limits.cpu: "2"
    limits.memory: 10Gi
```

Comment: Just create it as and when you create a new namespace

Comment: You have some namespaces and you need to create `ResourceQuota` objects for any of them? Some kind of automation?

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in solution for it, however as an option, you can use a `bash` script to achieve it.

This will create `ResourceQuota` objects in all namespaces except for `kube-system`:

```
#!/bin/bash

for ns in $(kubectl get ns -o jsonpath="{.items[*].metadata.name}"); # get all namespaces in cluster
do
  if [ $ns != kube-system ] # check if it's not kube-system namespace
  then 
  cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f - # body of kubectl apply -f
  apiVersion: v1
  kind: ResourceQuota
  metadata:
    name: resource-quota-$ns
    namespace: $ns
  spec:
    hard:
      requests.cpu: "2"
      requests.memory: 10Gi
      limits.cpu: "2"
      limits.memory: 10Gi
EOF
  fi
done
```

Useful link:

- [Create objects from stdout](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#creating-objects)

Comment: moonkotte, Thank you for response